# perl msgrcv() errno 22 (EINVAL) Ubuntu

Tags: perl, ubuntu, ipc, message-queue

I have two perl processes that communicate over System V IPC message Q on Ubuntu.

The receiver runs successfully for a time, receives messages in a poller function like this

```
sub getCompleteRecord { 

  while( msgrcv($q, $buff, $size, $msgType, &IPC_NOWAIT)  ) {
    # assemble record from messages and return           
  }

  # print $! error code

  #`here if nothing ready (42) or other error`
```

After some time I eventually get an error code 22 (EINVAL), which means invalid argument, and then subsequently all calls to msgrcv() fail with 22 *and* the separate sender process also cannot msgsnd(), again getting EIVAL.

When I restart the processes the queue can again be used.

Any suggestions for reasons, or how to approach diagnosing this?

As noted in the comments the meaning of the error code 22 is that either the msqid ($q) or the buffer size ($size) are incorrect. However, this is all happening in a loop, and those two values never change. I log the values before each call and I see many successes and then suddenly a failure for seemingly the same values.

> masterQueue 360448 read buffer size:5000 msgType1
> Message received
>
> --- many similar successes, then:
>
> masterQueue 360448 read buffer size:5000 msgType1
> read error 22=Invalid argument

And from this point both reader process and writer process fail. If I restart, then everything works for about 30 minutes and then fails again.

Comment: According to the C [manual](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/2-msgrcv/) : *"When `msgrcv()` fails, if `$! == EINVAL` it means that $q (msqid) was invalid, or `$size` (msgsz) was less than 0."*

Comment: @Håkon Hægland Yes, indeed, but these values never change. Why should the msgid suddenly become invalid? Npte that this seems to affect both parent and child, separate processes, which implies that it's something environmental rather than in my code.

Comment: Can you upload the scripts somewhere? Then we could try to reproduce.

Comment: Is there any chance that something might be deleting your message queue? Possibly some cron job or similar? Also, have you considered using POSIX message queues (as I think they're more robust to things like this)?

Comment: I will need to create a minimal test case because the real code is confidential. This body of code has been running for a couple of years on CentOS and Ubuntu, problem has happened only when we upgraded Ubuntu. I could look at switching to POSIX but I feel it should not be necessary - I'm going to double check cronjobs as those are a plausible candidate.

Comment: Does the size of the msg exceed 5000 bytes? You could also check the output of below command
ipcs -q -i <msgq_id>

Comment: @saai63 - my code should ensure that messages are sized correctly (I'm breaking up a larger structure into 5000 byte pieces) and in normal running this seems to be reliable. The code has been running for 2 years with no issues. Thanks for the ipcs -q -i suggestion.